# How do I combine a Google Calendar with a subscribed calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, subscriptions

I use Google Apps for my small business. So I have my main calendar there. I have a specific need:

I have more than one subscribed calendar, such as my travel itineraries from TripIt. They show up great when I look at my calendar, but are not visible to my colleagues unless I also share the TripIt calendar with them. I'd prefer a solution that duplicates the events on my TripIt calendar on my main Google Calendar so that my travel always shows. Is that possible?

Comment: Sharing the Tripit calendar is the easy way. If you don't want to share, then check this link on how to sync both the calendars https://www.tripit.com/uhp/calendarInfo. If you want to do programatically, then read all the events from the tripit and insert into the google calendar.